# Which input of NAND is preferred and why?

Tags: mosfet, cmos, timing, nand

Let A and B be two inputs of the NAND gate. Say input A arrives at the NAND gate later than input B. To optimize delay of the two series NMOS inputs A and B which one would you place near to the output?

Edit: Input A arrives Later than Input B. To optimize delay in the NMOS section. how do you place inputs A and B. [image]

Comment: Is signal A attached to input A or input B? (In other words: please avoid reusing variable names)

Comment: how do you know that one is closer to the output than the other?

Comment: Notice the lower A will directly experience the Miller effect of its gate-drain overlap capacitance, thus a stronger drive **may** be needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would place input A closer to the output. If input B switches first then the bottom NMOS transistor has time to bring the source capacitance of the top NMOS transistor fully to ground before input A goes high.

If input A goes high but the source terminal of its NMOS transistor is not at ground then the effective \$V_{GS}\$ for that transistor is reduced by the existing voltage at the source, thus reducing \$I_{DS}\$.

Comment: You asked "so that both inputs...arrive at the same time" but you don't control when the inputs arrive. I don't understand what you mean by "reduce the input delay A". I'm sorry but your comments don't make sense to me.

Comment: When (the bottom NMOS transistor has time to bring the source capacitance of the top NMOS transistor fully to the ground before input A goes high.) So, total Vdd is grounded and more Ids?

second case: Vgs = vdd-vt  and reducing Ids?